# Constructing a List of Interface that requires Type Argument via Dependency Injection in C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, architecture

I have a report like so:

```cs
public class Report : IReport
{
    public PageViewSection PageViews {get;set;}
}
```

Which has sections defined as such:

```cs
public class PageViewSection : IStateSection
{
}
```

Which uses data processing factories defined as such:

```cs
public class PageViewProcessor : IProcessor<PageViewSection>
{
}
```

And I'm attempting to use these factories in the report data repository:

```cs
public class DataRepository : IParticularReportTypeRepository
{
    private IProcessor[] _processors;
    
    public DataRepository(IProcessor[] processors)
    {
        _processors = processors;
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do, to have DI retrieve multiple instances of `IProcessor` without the type argument? There are going to eventually be hundreds of `IProcessor` instances, so writing a specific interface for each processor type seems unreasonable. I would love some architecture advice on how best to do this.

EDIT: Adding `IProcessor`:

```cs
public interface IProcessor<TReportSection>
{
    bool ShouldProcess(IncomingData data);
    TReportSection Process(IncomingData data, TReportSection section);
}
```

In the time since I've posted this I've considered architecting this such that the report sections are able to retrieve their processors.

Processors are used like so in the repo:

```cs
var reportSection = await GetReportSectionAsync(evt.EventTime, evt.ContextId);

foreach (var processor in _processors)
{
    processor.Process(evt, reportSection);
}

return await AddOrUpdateDocumentAsync(report);
```

Comment: Can you please provide contents of IProcessor<T>?

Comment: @opel Added some detail about IProcessor<T>.

Comment: Can you add some code that demonstrates how `DataRepository` is intended to use those processors? For instance, what's interesting to see is how it would loop through, and where the `TReportSection` would come from, and how `DataRepository` would use the returned `TReportSection`.

Comment: @Steven Added some repo detail, what I'm trying to do may not be possible...

Comment: What is the return type of `GetReportAsync`? Is that `object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `IProcessor<T>` implements a non-generic version `IProcessor`, it is impossible to inject them all into the constructor. But even if you do so, it forces you to iterate all processors, while it only makes sense to call the versions that implement `IProcessor<T>` where the `T` is the required type.

There are several ways to solve this problem. Here are two:

#### 1. Make `DataRepository` generic:

For instance:

```cs
public class DataRepository<TReportSection>
    : IParticularReportTypeRepository<TReportSection>
{
    private IProcessor<TReportSection>[] _processors;
    
    public DataRepository(IProcessor<TReportSection>[] processors)
    {
        _processors = processors;
    }

    public async Task<TReportSection> Process(IncomingData evt)
    {
        TReportSection reportSection = ...;

        foreach (var processor in _processors)
        {
            processor.Process(evt, reportSection);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

With this approach you would inject a specific `IParticularReportTypeRepository<TReportSection>` (e.g. `IParticularReportTypeRepository<PageViewSection>` into the constructor of a consumer.

This design is only possible when each consumer has only one (or a few types of report sections) that it passes on. Otherwise, consumers get many dependencies of type `IParticularReportTypeRepository<T>` in their constructors.

If you need a more dynamic approach, you can start using Reflection inside the `DataRepository` and (optionally) call back into the used DI Container. This is demonstrated next.

#### 2. Resolve collections from inside `DataRepository`:

For instance:

```cs
public class DataRepository : IParticularReportTypeRepository
{
    private readonly Container _container;
    
    public DataRepository(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public async Task<IStateSection> Process(IncomingData evt)
    {
        IStateSection reportSection =
            await GetReportSectionAsync(evt.EventTime, evt.ContextId);
            
        Type processorType =
            typeof(IProcessor<>).MakeGenericType(reportSection.GetType())
        
        IEnumerable<object> processors =
            _container.GetAllInstances(processorType);

        // NOTE the dynamic keywords here.
        foreach (dynamic processor in processors)
        {
            processor.Process(evt, (dynamic)reportSection);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

With this implementation, `DataRepository` only knows during the call to its `Process` method what type of processor it needs. It does so by constructing a closed generic version of `IProcessor<T>` and asks the DI Container to return a list of them. Note that the API calls might look different depending on the DI Container you use. You should review your container's documentation to find out how to resolve collections. If you don't use a DI Container, you might want to inject an `Func<Type, IEnumerable<object>>` factory delegate instead.

> **IMPORTANT:** Because of the dependency on the DI Container, this class should now be part of your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

The `DataRepository.Process` method makes use of Reflection and calls the processor using C#'s `dynamic` keyword. This isn't per se the best approach (there are some downsides to it), but it produces the least amount of code, which is useful for demonstration purposes. Jimmy Bogard recently [did an article](https://jimmybogard.com/crossing-the-generics-divide/) that demonstrated two different approaches concerning the invocation of generic types. You might want to take a look at that article.

Comment: Went with #2, thank you for the suggested solutions.